# Update ICommand after ViewModel creation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I am writing a WPF application to learn the MVVM Design Pattern. I am fairly new to C# and WPF.

I am trying to pass some context when switching ViewModels, that then gets used in an ICommand implementation to call a method. But the ICommand won't update after receiving the context.

Basically I create an instance of an ICommand, which a button binds to and then (when passing the context) I create another instance that replaces it.

My question then: is there a way to rebind a command binding or is the state it had at the time of intialization unmodifiable.

What I'm trying to accomplish in code:

**Command.cs**

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    public Command(Action action) => this.action = action;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public virtual void Execute(object parameter) => action();

    Action action;
}
```

**ObservableObject.cs**

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**FooModel.cs**

```
public class FooModel
{
    public int Number => 10;
}
```

**BarModel.cs**

```
public class BarModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

**BarViewModel.cs**

```
public class BarViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public BarViewModel()
    {
        Bar = new BarModel();
        BtnCommand = new Command(Reset);
    }
    public void Receive(object state)
    {
        if (state is FooModel foo)
        {
            Counter = Bar.Number = foo.Number;
            // this won't reset the number to 10
            BtnCommand = new Command(Reset);
            // neither will this, why?
            Reset();
        }
    }       
    public void Reset() => Counter = Bar.Number;
    int counter;
    public int Counter
    {
        get => counter;
        set
        {
            counter = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Counter));
        }
    }
    Command btnCommand;
    public Command BtnCommand
    {
        get => btnCommand;
        set
        {
            btnCommand = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(BtnCommand));
        }
    }
    BarModel Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

**BarView.xaml**

```
<UserControl
    <! ... namespaces and such -->
        >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:BarViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding BtnCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `Receive` Method is invoked after creating the `BarViewModel` and it passes an instance of `FooModel`. When I set a breakpoint inside the `if (state ...)` block it says that the `Bar.Number` field is 10, but when it leaves the scope it's back to 0. I get a feeling that this is how it's supposed to work, but how can I accomplish the update of the Command context?

I tried to create a MCVE of my project, here's the link to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pp83audvicioeje/FooBar.zip?dl=0). It's a VS 2017 Project using .NET 4.5.2

Screenshot of code in MCVE:

[image]

*EDIT: changed fileupload URL*

*EDIT2: added screenshot*

*EDIT3: updated code*

*EDIT4: changed fileupload to dropbox*

Comment: Kindly paste code in as text, not screenshots. In the exceedingly rare case where it's appropriate to post a download link, use Dropbox or Github.

Comment: You need to step through the code in the debugger. It's probably something quite simple. I'm suspicious of this claim, because you don't show the code that does it it: *"The Receive Method is invoked after creating the BarViewModel and it passes an instance of FooModel"*. This line will obviously not call `Reset()`: `BtnCommand = new Command(Reset);`

Comment: `Counter = Bar.Number = foo.Number;` What is `foo.Number`? Zero? Where in the block did you set that breakpoint you mentioned?

Comment: This design looks suspiciously convoluted to me. I suspect it can be greatly simplified.

Comment: That may be true, as I said I'm not that experienced. I'll try to rethink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the `BarViewModel` in your `Bar` view. Remove this XAML markup:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:BarViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Then the commands that you create in your `Receive` method should be invoked as expected.